# int() is not changing float number into an integer in try block statement

Tags: exception, try-catch

Below is the code I'm trying to run. But it's giving me exception even when I'm giving float as a number?

Why is it so? `int()` can easily convert a float into an int.

```
while True:
    try:
        x=int(input("Enter the value: "))
        break
    except:
        print("Not a Valid Number")
    finally:
        print("Attemt Done")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not converting a float into an int, you are converting a *string* into an int (and e.g. `3.2` is not a valid integer). On the other hand, this would not raise a `ValueError` (as `3.2` is a valid float, and a float can be cast to int):

```
x = int(float(input("Enter the value: ")))
```

Writing it explicitly allows you to exactly control what is happening.

Comment: thanks for the answer! But my concern is, suppose when i give 23 as an input (that is also a string), it successfully runs but not when i input 23.5 (that is a string too). 23 and 23.5 -- both are strings as input  then where is the difference?

Comment: `'23'` is a valid representation of an integer, so `int` doesn't complain. `'23.5'` is not.

Comment: ok that helps!  but i want to run the code regardless what value is given--int or float. so i ran below and it was successful:
x=int(float(input("Enter the value: ")))

But it still doesn't run if i interchange int and float:
x=float(int(input("Enter the value: ")))

To add error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Try_first.py", line 9, in <module>
    print (x)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined